# How to get list of mock files in dropzone.js?

Tags: dropzone.js

I am adding files to my dropzone as instructed in [documentation](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-show-files-already-stored-on-server). Then later I would like to check dropzone if it has any added mock files. Is there a way I could achieve this? Dropzone.files seems to be empty. It contains only the files uploaded in current session.

I am adding files like this:

```
var mockFile = { name: "Image1", size: fileSize };
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "images/img.jpg");
myDropzone.files.push(mockFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use myDropzone.files.push(mockFile), when adding you mock files.

Comment: Sorry, that part was missing. Of course I am adding the files to the array, that isn't the case.

Comment: You can also add to you mock file new property: mockFile.IsMock = true, and later check this.